# How to package from source?

Tags: package-management, packaging

I would like to package Nagios 4 on Ubuntu. Installation from source involves multiple make commands and a configure command.

```
wget -O nagioscore.tar.gz https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nagioscore/archive/nagios-4.3.4.tar.gz
tar xzf nagioscore.tar.gz
cd /tmp/nagioscore-nagios-4.3.4/
./configure --with-httpd-conf=/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
make all
make install
make install-init
make install-commandmode
make install-config
make install-webconf
```

How do I make a deb or apt package out of this?

I tried following the Ubuntu instructions
http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html
When I run the `bzr dh-make package version package.tar.gz`, I get the following error

```
bzr: ERROR: Either run the command from an existing branch of upstream, or move nagioscore-nagios-4.3.4 aside and a new branch will be created there.
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the set of instructions your followed, and exactly what you did that produced this error?

Comment: How To Package is an enormous topic, filling whole websites (http://mentors.debian.net , http://packaging.ubuntu.com). AskUbuntu is more appropriate for a more limited question.

Comment: @darksky I updated the question with procedure. I get an error in the 'starting a package' part

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks! I will try that. I do not know if that would work for multiple make commands.

Comment: @DavidFoerster that checkinstall solution partially solved my problem. It only performs a `make install`. The other `make install` commands generate config files which I can copy over.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo:

> If you got this far, you've done the hardest part already. Now all you
>   need to do is run the command
>
> ```
> make which does the actual building (compiling) of the program.
> ```
>
> If it's a large program or if you've got a very slow computer, go and
>   get a cup of coffee or something. If you have a multi-core processor
>   you can also set the variable CONCURRENCY_LEVEL to the number of
>   processors/cores you have to speed things up a little.
>
> When it's done, install the program. You probably want to use `sudo checkinstall` which puts the program in the package manager for clean, easy removal later. This replaces the old `sudo make install`
>   command.

Comment: @darksky Please review my edit and reverse downvoting (if necessary) if my edit fixed the problem that you commented about.

Comment: @darksky Whoops, I'm an idiot. I didn't even know that existed.